# Vostro 3700 laptop WS 2008 R2 Hyper-V kills sound

Tags: hyper-v

We have an odd problem that I am stumped on.  We just purchased two Dell Vostro 3700 laptops, they came with Windows 7 Pro installed.  We have installed Windows Server 2008 R2 on each of the laptops which all works great until we enable Hyper-V.  When we do this the sound will stop working correctly and becomes crackly and unusable.  If Hyper-V is removed the sound returns.  We are at a loss of how to fix this issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask how Hyper-V server with WS2008 R2 is not professional IT?  We are an ECommerce Shop and use these as our day to day work stations.

Answer (score 1):

Driver updates-  that is it. When you install Hyper-V, the "shell" runs in a virtual machine (0).... which has different sheduling properties than the native machine.

I could only point fingers to the sound and posibly lower level hardware drivers.

Comment: I did try the Windows 7 64 bit drivers, will see if I can find anything better. Thx

Comment: They should work fine. I would say you need more modern ones. That said, I dont run hyper-v on workstations, so - i ahve no clue whether this actually is a "hard" problem, or one that is supposedly easy and specific to your hardware.